# iOS: Core Data NSFetchRequest for one entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two entities: Plan and Instrument with a relationship "one to many" (a plan can have more instruments)

Then I want to check if an instrument with a serial exist in my DB, but I want to check if it exist in its Plan and not il all entire DB, I do this but it don't work because it search in all DB, what can I do?

```
NSFetchRequest *req_exixts = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Plan"];
    [req_exixts setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY instrument.serial_number =[cd] %@", serialNumber]];
```

Comment: why wouldn't you try to make it from the side of instruments? fetch all instruments with predicate @"plan = @ && serial_number = %@", planObject, serialNumber ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have a mismatch with the name of entity "instrument" and the relationShip between "Plan" and "Instrument". In your case if you fetch a Plan entity you must use the relationship name to Instrument entity in the fetchRequest and the keyword "ANY" is not necessary.